# Gather the count of a specific object from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, enumeration

Hey guys & girls,
Im wondering how I can find the object count of a specific type of object in an array.
For example, i have 6 'clouds' in NSMutableArray at random locations, I also have 4 'dragons' in this NSMutableArray.

How can i gather the integer 6?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
int z = [[SomeClass *clouds in _somearray] count];
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thnx,
Oliver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int result = 0;
for (NSObject *object in _somearray) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]])
        result++;
}
```

`result` is the count you are looking for

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way is in using blocks:

```
Class cloadClass = NSClassFromString(@"Cloud");
NSArray *a = /* you array with clouds and dragons */;

NSIndexSet *clouds = [a indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: 
    ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isKindOfClass:cloadClass];
    }];

// now we can count clouds
NSLog(@"%d", [clouds count]);

// but also we now can return our clouds immediately and
NSLog(@"%@", [a objectsAtIndexes:clouds]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for how many times a specific *instance* of an object appears, you can do:

```
NSCountedSet *counts = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:myArrayOfObjects];
NSUInteger count = [counts countForObject:myObject];
```

Otherwise you'd just have to loop through the array manually and count.